# How to get each committer's code coverage report

Tags: unit-testing

If a merge request is committed by two programmers, A and B, A committed 100 lines and B 10 lines, the unittest covers 90 lines for A and 2 lines for B(this was calculated manually), how to get each committer's code coverage report automatically, by a script or by some api, or some other tools?